# Mi sitio Web IIS no es accesible por IP

Tags: iis

Cuando entro a mi sitio de la siguiente manera `www.test.com` puedo visualizar mi sitio correctamente  pero para entrar por IP es decir: `http://10.60.113.173`  visualizo mi sitio pero sin estilos y si detengo el APACHE simplemente no muestra mi sitio.

Cabe mencionar que tengo configurada mi zona primaria y la zona inversa para hacer búsqueda por dominio y por IP y al hacer ping obtengo respuesta satisfactoria.

Comment: tu problema no son los estilos, es como tienes las rutas definidas en tu HTML

Comment: momento, ¿Es IIS o Apache?

Comment: ¿Te pasa con todos los navegadores? ¿Comprobaste si en tu código HTML tienes urls relativas o absolutas? Fíjate con las herramientas de desarrollador de Chrome o con Firebug de Firefox si te están cargando bien tus recursos (CSS, JS...) y si no, comprueba a que ruta están intentando acceder y nos comentas.

Comment: @JackNavaRow  te comento ya habia cargado este proyecto en otra comptadora y se ejecuta super bien  sin problemas las rutas las tengo bien definidas mi proyecto esta desarrollado en cakephp 3, este error me paso en otra maquina donde también tienen ejecutado en Apache  hice la misma configuración pero al hacer la busqueda por IP no funciona me di cuenta que tenían ejecutando el apache lo detuve y no muestra nada

Comment: @jackNavaRow Si, si tengo definido que lea php,  por eso cuando entra con la ruta www.test.com si funciona veo mi sitio correctamente el detalle es cuando quiero accesar por ip

Comment: cuando cargas la pagina, que url tienes en los css? abre la consola de tu web browser